# Check if there's incoming data in serial port linux (cbInQue for linux)

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port, port

I'm having a trouble with managing data coming into a linux serial port from an Arduino unit.

Basically, I have a working code to read and print out (or just store) but it is written for windows platform:

status is of type COMSTAT

```
int SerialPort::readSerialPort(char *buffer, unsigned int buf_size)
{
  DWORD bytesRead;
  unsigned int toRead = 0;
  Sleep(500);
  ClearCommError(this->handler, &this->errors, &this->status);

  if (this->status.cbInQue > 0) { //if there's something to read 
    if (this->status.cbInQue > buf_size) {//if there's something to read&bigger than buffer size
        toRead = buf_size; //read as much as buffer alows 
    }
    else toRead = this->status.cbInQue; //else just read as much as there is
}

if (ReadFile(this->handler, buffer, toRead, &bytesRead, NULL))
    return bytesRead; //return read data


return 0;//return 0 if nothing is there.
}
```

apart from Sleep() that is windows function, I was wondering if there is an equivalent linux function for status.cbInQue to understand if there is any data that is ready to be read in the port. 
Right now I just go ahead and read, without checking, and often I get nothing printed later in the program.

TLDR: is there cbInQue equivalent for linux?

Thanks

Comment: You can read the serial port in Linux, for example `cat /dev/ttyS0` so that you will see is there any traffic going on. It's just for the sake of debugging to know what your program is doing.

Comment: Well generally I do get serial input from the arduino, but I checked for the easiest case when the arduino sends something non stop like "Hello World from Arduino". I'm looking for a-C++ implementation so I can apply it as a safety net in the code. That's how I can run it and wait till there's anything (and only then read it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will need your file descriptor and then use `FIONREAD` to see if anything is available.

Something like the following should work:

```
int available;
if( ioctl( fd, FIONREAD, &available ) < 0 ) {
    // Error handling here
}
```